# Loop switch statement

Tags: loops, switch-statement

how can i now loop this switch statement? Because after i looped that statement i want to write a code that adds the text text to the site as soon as one of the keys is pressed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>      
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        document.onkeydown = function(event) {
            switch(event.keyCode) { 
            case 13:
                    document.write("Use weapon");
                    break;
            case 50:
                    document.write("Switch weapon");
                    break;
            case 32:
                    document.write("Jump");
                    break;
            case 38:
                    document.write("Run Forward");
                    break;
            }
            return event.returnValue;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by loop?

Comment: I mean that the switch statement should be reasked as soon as i press one of these buttons

Comment: Your username is asking for downvote bombardment by jerky "pros".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"I mean that the switch statement should be reasked as soon as i press one of these buttons"** – Codenoob, comment to question

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>      
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var trackKeyCommand = function(){
        document.onkeydown = function(event) {
            switch(event.keyCode) { 
            case 13:
                    document.write("Use weapon");
                    document.write("<br />");
                    trackKeyCommand();
                    break;
            case 50:
                    document.write("Switch weapon");
                    document.write("<br />");
                    trackKeyCommand();
                    break;
            case 32:
                    document.write("Jump");
                    document.write("<br />");
                    trackKeyCommand();
                break;
            case 38:
                    document.write("Run Forward");
                    document.write("<br />");
                    trackKeyCommand();
                break;
            }
            return event.returnValue;
        }
    }
    trackKeyCommand();
</script>
```

What I did was create a function, **trackKeyCommand**. After any one of the four keys (ENTER, SPACE, UP, and 2) is pressed, it calls the function again, resulting in a loop.

I also put a line break after each phrase; I found it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. *onkeydown* fires continuously when the key is held down.
If you just want it to fire only once, then use *onkeypress* instead. *onkeypress* is fired once every time a key is pressed.

Either way, you don't need a loop.

You can refer to [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeydown.asp) for more information on *onkeydown*. 
They also have a test page for the event over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onkeydown).

Comment: The problem i have is that i want to add text as soon as the key is pressed, but at the moment it only shows text to the pressed key once and doesnt change then. I thought i could solve this by looping the statement and adding a value instead of document.write to the end so text is gonna add as soon as a key is pressed